# Create a function that selects rows in a data frame based on if the elements of two column belong to a list in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe s1

```
s1=data.frame(no=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),col=c("red","green","blue","yellow","blue","black","white"),car_mod=c("car2","car4","car1","car5","car7","car3","car1"))

  no    col car_mod
1  1    red    car2
2  2  green    car4
3  3   blue    car1
4  4 yellow    car5
5  5   blue    car7
6  6  black    car3
7  7  white    car1
```

and a list l

```
l=list(list(c("green","blue","red"),c("car1","car2","car5")))

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "green" "blue"  "red"  

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "car1" "car2" "car5"
```

I want to create a function which only selects the rows in which the element in the column "col" and the element in the column "car_mod" are present in the list ( the element in col should be present in l[1][1] while car_mod should be present in l[1][2])

The output should look something like this

```
s_new=data.frame(no=c(1,3),col=c("red","blue"),car_mod=c("car2","car1"))

  no  col car_mod
1  1  red    car2
2  3 blue    car1
```

Note, the actual dataframe and list are very large.
I tried doing something like this

```
for(i in l[1]){
  for(j in l[2]){ 
    if(i %in% s1$col & j %in% s1$car_mod){
      select()
    }
   
   
  }
  
}
```

But im not sure how to proceed or if using loops is the best approach due to the size of the dataframe

Comment: Isn't this just a simple exercise in subsetting, i.e., `s1[s1$col %in% l[[1]][[1]] & s1$car_mod %in% l[[1]][[2]],]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `subset` (or `dplyr::filter`):

`> subset(s1, col %in% l[[1]][[1]] & car_mod %in% l[[1]][[2]])`

```
  no  col car_mod
1  1  red    car2
3  3 blue    car1
```

Answer (score 0):

A posible solution with filter:

```
s_new <- s1 %>% filter(col %in% l[[1]][1][[1]] & car_mod %in% l[[1]][2][[1]])
```

> s_new

```
  no  col car_mod
1  1  red    car2
2  3 blue    car1
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the `[[` you can also use `pluck()` from the `purrr` package:

```
library(tidyverse)

s_new <- s1 %>% filter(col %in% pluck(pluck(l, 1), 1) & car_mod %in% pluck(pluck(l, 1), 2))
```